# Spark (v 2.3.2) dataframe is reading all the columns in an ORC file as string type. is this a normal behaviour?

Tags: apache-spark, orc

I have a bunch of CSV files that are being loaded into HDFS in ORC format using the ETL tool Informatica. After the load into HDFS, I wanted to extract the metadata (column names, data types) of the ORC files.

But when I loaded the ORC files into Spark dataframes, all the columns are being evaludated as `string` type.

Sample Data:

```
ID|Course|Enrol_Date|Credits
123|Biology|21-03-2012 07:34:56|24
908|Linguistics|05-02-2012 11:02:36|15
564|Computer Science|18-03-2012 09:48:09|30
341|Philosophy|23-01-2012 18:12:44|10
487|Math|10-04-2012 17:00:46|20
```

I'm using the below commands to achieve this:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM orc.`<HDFS_path>`");
df.printSchema()
```

Sample output:

```
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Course: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Enrol_Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Credits: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm totally new to Spark and HDFS. I'm trying to understand why every column is result in `string` type. Is this the normal behaviour when creating ORCs with csv source files (irrespective of which tool we use to do it)? Or am I not doing something correctly in spark that is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

By default, spark reads all fields as *StringType* . You can try below:

For inferring schema,

```
val data = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("<path>.csv")
```

For providing custom schema

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val customSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("col1", StringType, true),
  StructField("col2", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("col3", DoubleType, true))
)

val data = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").schema(customSchema).load("<path>.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But giving a custom schema is not an efficient way in my case because I have files with very large number of columns. Hence my pursuit to extract the datatype info automatically instead of providing manually. I need this info for creating external tables in Hive.

Comment: Actually , providing the custom schema is the efficient way even with 100's of columns. Because , when you are inferring schema , spark goes through every data point & infers , effectively reading through the whole data. But when you provide schema, effectively you are saving the time to infer

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't know that. Thanks for clarifying. What I meant by inefficient is that I have to type the datatypes manually for each of those 100s of columns. But what you say also makes sense in terms of reducing the load on spark. I will keep that in mind for relevant situations. But right now, I'm in a situation where I do not know how many columns a file might have or their data types. My sole purpose right now is to form the `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` statement in Hive using this information.

Comment: Even Databricks videos state this

Answer (score 1):

You should `cast` or use `schema` while import `CSV` file through **Informatica**. Since **Spark** `ORC` format does not `infer Schema` automatically like Spark `CSV` format. ORC format take schema from source file schema as it is.

Since you have not used any `schema` in **Informatica**, it has written data in default `String` DataType which is further taken by `ORC`.

There are two possible way to resolve issue:

1. Either use Schema in CSV file (transform columns that should have
   data type other that `String`) in `Informatica`/`Spark` and load into `ORC`.
2. Or use `Struct` or `Casting` in Spark to change datatype of `ORC` file for required columns.

**Sample Demonstration:**

Below is sample demonstration of How spark work with `Schema`. You can resemble logic of Schema of source `CSV` file in `Informatica` same as `Spark` give as below

> Case 1: Default loading CSV file and write into ORC

```
scala> val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("/spath/stack2.csv")

//Default schema uses by Spark or Informatica for CSV file

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Course: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Enrol_Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Credits: string (nullable = true)

//Have loaded same CSV file into ORC

scala> df.write.format("orc").mode("overwrite").save("/spath/AP_ORC")

scala> val orc = spark.read.format("orc").load("/spath/AP_ORC")

//Schema is same as Source CSV file

scala> orc.printSchema
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Course: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Enrol_Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Credits: string (nullable = true)
```

> Case 2:Transformation/inferring Schema datatype for CSV file and write into ORC

```
//Inferring Schema or Transform/casting of CSV data in Spark or Informatica respectively. 

scala> val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferschema", "true").load("/spath/stack2.csv")

//Transformed Schema
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Course: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Enrol_Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Credits: integer (nullable = true)

//Have loaded same CSV file into ORC

scala> df.write.format("orc").mode("overwrite").save("/spath/AP_ORC")

scala> val orc = spark.read.format("orc").load("/spath/AP_ORC")

 //Schema is same as Source CSV file

scala> orc.printSchema
root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Course: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Enrol_Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Credits: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I just tried this but still it gave all the columns as `string` type. Could there be a reason why this is the case?

Comment: could you check how you are loading data through Informatica, Are you using any schema

Comment: could you provide your sample data

Comment: Edited the question to add sample data and its output. And, no I'm not using any schema in Informatica. It's a dynamic mapping that picks each file using a paremeter.